# How to clear the value of ion-datetime ionic4

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I am trying to clear the ion-datetime component on button click but i have no idea how to go about it. Can anyone help?.

Comment: try by using ngModel/formControl.

Comment: I use ngModel and i tried setting the value of ngModel to "" but it still doesnt work